# Calculating distance of cannon shot using utility tests in c# console application

Tags: c#, testing, console-application, utility, trigonometry

I'm trying to calculate distance of cannon shot using velocity and angle. I'm testing results using utility tests. The formula for range should be someting like **v^2 * sin2a** aka **velocity squared * sin2alpha** . As far as i know, sin2a is supposed to be **2*sina*cosa**, but i may be wrong.

Anyway, whatever i do, i get wrong results, because it doesn't seem to be calculating **sin**.

Here's the code

**Cannon.cs**

```
public int CalculateDistance(int angle, int velocity)
    {
        int distance = 0;
        double radian_angle = (Math.PI / 180) * angle;
        distance_of_shot = (Math.Pow(velocity, 2)) * (2 * Math.Sin(radian_angle) * Math.Cos(radian_angle));
        distance = (int)distance_of_shot;
        return distance;
    }
```

**CannonAttackTest.cs**

```
[TestMethod]
    public void Calculations()
    {
        Canon new_canon = new Canon();
        var data = new_canon.CalculateDistance(45, 450);
        Assert.AreEqual(20682, data);                      
    }
```

The results is suppose to be 20682, but i get 202500, which is exactly a number of squared 450...whichs points to sin not being calculated.

[image]

**Any help is appreciated!**

**Thank you!**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check your units, you need to divide by the value of "g" because velocity is m/s and your "distance of shot" is in m^2/s^2.

```
distance_of_shot = (Math.Pow(velocity, 2)) * (2 * Math.Sin(radian_angle) * Math.Cos(radian_angle))/9.81;
```

Comment: that kinda makes sense yes. but i still get 20663 instead of 20682?

Comment: @fox Ok divide by 9.81, a more accurate value of g. There, homework done ;)

Answer (score 0):

You have a mistake sin 0.70710678118654746 and cos 0.70710678118654757 but after
(2 * Math.Sin(radian_angle) * Math.Cos(radian_angle)) result coming 1